# Firefox CSS nowrap problem

Tags: css, firefox, nowrap

I'm trying to create a horizontal (no line breaks) unordered list of images on my website using code as follows:

```
<ul class="ImageSet">
    <li>
        <img src="blah">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="blah">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="blah">
    </li>
</ul>
```

In my CSS, I'm using the following rules:

```
.ImageSet { white-space: nowrap; }
.ImageSet li { display: inline; float: left; height: 100% }
```

This is working properly in Chrome, but not in Firefox, for some reason does anyone know why?

EDIT: To clarify, the problem in FF is that the li's still wrap. I'm trying to make them all appear in a single, unbroken horizontal line going off the rightmost edge of the page.

Comment: What is the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: How exactly is it different in Firefox?

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. The li's are stacking vertically (the pictures are each really wide).

Comment: not for me! rendering is identical for me b/w chrome and FF. Here's a sample I tried http://jsfiddle.net/zCuXb/

Comment: I don't see what you describe http://jsfiddle.net/jZLrj/

Comment: @Sotiris http://jsfiddle.net/6kQDw/ see ? that won't stay on the same line. nowrap is specified, so why ? And it works well on chrome. firefokken !

Comment: @Ben works the same for me in both browsers.

Comment: @sotiris sorry i was getting a bit nervous the oother day. but clearly the line break is there event if wordwrapped -> http://cl.ly/image/3G223J2R2x3R should it be there ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing `float:left` as `display:inline` should suffice

Comment: In fact `float: left` forces `display: block`, so it's doubly wrong.

Comment: `display: inline-block` should work a bit better if there was a block behavior with `float:left` before :)

Comment: As far as i am aware, (maybe this has changed) but inline-block is not cross-browser

Answer (score 0):

When you float li's they will wrap when they reach the end of their parent container (which could be the body tag). If you are wanting the image to disappear out of the screen you will need to set the width of the parent container (the ul) and use overflow hidden or auto to get your desired effect.